# POSTGRES aggregate data from joined table

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-9.1

There is sql-query, running in POSTGRES 9.1. That query uses 24 LEFT JOINs.
Every joined table is able to have from 1 to 10-15 data rows, related to the previous table. As a result of sql-query I have very many data rows, differing from each other by 1 value

SQL-query example:

```
SELECT
   asw.surname,
   asw.firstname,
   asw.fathername,
   asw.birthday,
   asbe.institue_title,
   asht.honour_type
  /* Other fields are hidden to simplify example */
FROM
    /* Table of staff */ 
    agency_socworker AS asw 
LEFT JOIN
    /* Table contains staff honours */ 
    agency_socworkerhonours AS ash 
    ON asw.id = ash.socworker_id 
LEFT JOIN
    /* Table contains name of the certain honour_id */ 
    agency_socworker_honourtype AS asht 
    ON ash.honour_name_id = asht.id 
LEFT JOIN
    /* Table contains education data */ 
    agency_socworker_base_edu AS asbe 
    ON asbe.socworker_id = asw.id 
/* Other part of query is hidden to simplify example */
ORDER BY
    asw.surname ASC
```

Result example:

```
surname---firstname---fathername---birthday-----honour_type----institue_title1
Surname---firstname---fathername---1965-01-01---TYPE1----------institue_title1
Surname---firstname---fathername---1965-01-01---TYPE2----------institue_title1
Surname---firstname---fathername---1965-01-01---TYPE3----------institue_title1
Surname---firstname---fathername---1965-01-01---TYPE4----------institue_title1
Surname---firstname---fathername---1965-01-01---TYPE5----------institue_title1

Surname---firstname---fathername---1965-01-01---TYPE1----------institue_title2
Surname---firstname---fathername---1965-01-01---TYPE2----------institue_title2
Surname---firstname---fathername---1965-01-01---TYPE3----------institue_title2
Surname---firstname---fathername---1965-01-01---TYPE4----------institue_title2
Surname---firstname---fathername---1965-01-01---TYPE5----------institue_title2
```

I want to get the following:

```
surname---firstname---fathername---birthday--------honour_type----------------------institue_title
Surname---firstname---fathername---1965-01-01---TYPE1, TYPE2, TYPE3, TYPE4, TYPE5---institue_title1, institue_title2
```

I used array_agg function to achieve this goal:

```
SELECT
    asw.surname,
    asw.firstname,
    asw.fathername,
    asw.birthday,
    array_agg( asbe.institue_title ) AS honour_type
    array_agg( asht.honour_type ) AS honour_type
    /* Other fields are hidden to simplify example */
    FROM
        /* Table of staff */ 
        agency_socworker AS asw 
    LEFT JOIN
        /* Table contains staff honours */ agency_socworkerhonours AS ash 
        ON asw.id = ash.socworker_id 
    LEFT JOIN
        /* Table contains name of the certain honour_id */ 
        agency_socworker_honourtype AS asht 
          ON ash.honour_name_id = asht.id 
    LEFT JOIN
        /* Table contains education data */ 
        agency_socworker_base_edu AS asbe 
        ON asbe.socworker_id = asw.id 
GROUP BY
    asw.surname,
    asw.firstname,
    asw.fathername,
    asw.birthday
ORDER BY
    asw.surname ASC
```

But this requires "GROUP BY" statement to the fields not in "array_agg" function. As full SQL-query contains 24 joined tables I must use

```
GROUP BY
    asw.surname,
    asw.firstname,
    asw.fathername,
    asw.birthday,
    ag.shortname,
    agr.shortname,
    agr.fullname,
    agdis.shortname,
    agdis.fullname,
    aorg.name,
    agc.name,
    agc.atype,
    asnji.id,
    asnji.new_job_contract_date,
    assp.struct_name,
    agdep.number,
    agdep_type.name,
    agdep_type.dtype,
    aswl.work_length_checkdate,
    aswl.work_length_protection_length_years,
    aswl.work_length_protection_length_days,
    aswl.work_length_protection_length_months
```

This slows the query. With "group by" it takes 2 seconds to get the first 100 data rows. Without "array_agg" and "group by" statements it takes 250 ms, but I must have pagination. I cant do pagination as I dont know how much data rows gets me 100 unique rows.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is to pre aggregate and rejoin. I'm not sure about the performance impact, but there are much less group by expressions. Use the same technique with the other tables

```
with asw_agg as (
    select
        asw.id,
        array_agg(asbe.institue_title) as institute_title,
        array_agg(asht.honour_type) as honour_type
    from
        agency_socworker asw 
        left join
        agency_socworkerhonours ash on asw.id = ash.socworker_id 
        left join
        agency_socworker_honourtype asht on ash.honour_name_id = asht.id 
        left join
        agency_socworker_base_edu asbe on asbe.socworker_id = asw.id 
    group by asw.id
)
select
    asw.surname,
    asw.firstname,
    asw.fathername,
    asw.birthday,
    asw_agg.honour_type,
    asw_agg.institute_title
from
    asw
    inner join
    asw_agg using (id)
order by asw.surname asc
```

Comment: Thanks a million!
I will try. I think you are right, it is the best possible solution. I want to vote you answer up, but I can't :(